# How do I fill an array with 0 (or Nan) using other array as a reference?

Tags: python, arrays, reference, fillna

I have an array like this:

```
array(['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809', 'ENST00000454343'], 
['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809', 'ENST00000446805', 'ENST00000454343'], 
['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000454343'],
['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809', 'ENST00000454343', 'ENST00000600166'])
```

but I want to all follow the same reference, because they have to maintain this order:

```
array(['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809', 'ENST00000446805',
       'ENST00000454343', 'ENST00000468795', 'ENST00000600166'])
```

I don't want just to complete with zeros in the end, I want to fill with 0 the missing values according to the reference array, so they all end up with 6 elements

For example, for the array

```
['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809', 'ENST00000454343']
```

the final output should be:

```
['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809',0, 'ENST00000454343', 0, 0]
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if the second reference is missing, you'll have something along the lines of : `array(['ENST00000003084', 0, 'ENST00000446805','ENST00000454343', 'ENST00000468795', 'ENST00000600166'])`  ?

Comment: problem is not clear. You want missing strings to be replace by 0 in the second array ? by inserting some 0 ? please detail expected output and show a piece of code we can try and help : see [MRE].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I eddited the question, sorry for the unclear problem, I'm new on the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should solve your problem.

```
ref = np.array(['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809', 'ENST00000446805',
       'ENST00000454343', 'ENST00000468795', 'ENST00000600166'])
a = np.array(['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809', 'ENST00000454343'])
b = [ref[k] if ref[k] in a else 0 for k in range(len(ref))]
```

The output of this example is

```
['ENST00000003084', 'ENST00000426809', 0, 'ENST00000454343', 0, 0]
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer!!, I'm new on python and fail on easy tasks